# Conditional statement in C with nested if else else if

Tags: c, if-statement

Found this code in a book:

```
if(a > b)
    if(c > b) printf("one");
    else if(c == a) printf("two");
    else printf("three");
else printf("four");
```

**The question was:**
*The program will never print*
`a. one
 b. two
 c. three
 d. four`

The correct answer is `b. two`

Here, I cannot understand why it will not print `two`, as in the condition given, `c` can equal `a` and `c` can be greater than `b` at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is greater than `b`, and `c` is not greater than `b`, `c` can never be equal to `a`.

You can distribute the conditions:

`one` will print when `a > b && c > b`.

`two` will print when `a > b && c <= b && c == a`. Because of `c == a`, these conditions are equivalent to `c > b && c <= b`, which can never be true.

Comment: Clear.. Thumbs Up!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the else. Specifically, to get to that clause, a > b and c !> b (because if c > b, “one” would print). Thus, since c !> b, c  b, then c != a, so “two” cannot be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it, if you rewrite the code logically:

- if `a ≤ b`, case "four"
- if `a > b AND c > b`, case "one"
- if `a > b AND c ≤ b AND c = a`, case "two"
- if `a > b AND c ≤ b AND c ≠ a`, case "three"

The only case you can rewrite is the third bullet because with `c = a` you have:

> if a > b AND c ≤ b AND c = a

which is logically equivalent to

> if a > b AND a ≤ b

Which is never true for any value of `a` and `b`

Answer (score -3):

you used else in 4 th and 5 th lines.
you can not use else statment two times.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the `else` each refer to different `if`.